# DynamicReports won't work when exported to a runnable jar

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, executable-jar, dynamic-reports

I coded this app that uses dynamic reports.

I work with eclipse, and everything worked fine when I was working on eclipse.

today, I exported it to a runnable jar in order to implement it,
my app works fine, until I try to generate a report,
than it just gets stuck and do nothing.

if I look at the console window, its just stops here :

```
  log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger     (net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment).
  log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

on eclipse I always had these messages , and than the report launched.

any ideas ?
please help.

thanks
Dave.

Comment: check if the jar includes the configuration for log4j, set it to debug and try again, posting the log

Comment: set what to debug ? and how do I include the configuration for log4j? I don't use log4j in my app, I know dynamic reports needs it, but it is not mandatory..

Comment: the console output you got means the problems your application has are not being reported, thus making you - or anyone - unable to see what's wrong. With that configuration you would have a log that had probably said  that a ClassNotFoundException was thrown, pointing you toward the "it's not finding its dependencies"

Comment: I have the same issue, Any one has any solution ? `ResultSet resultSet;   
Connection conn = JdbcConnectionFactory.getInstance().getSqliteConnection(dbURL);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(rptPortQuery);  
JasperReportBuilder reportBuilder = AdhocManager.createReport(config.getReport(),new ReportFrameTemplate(strategyReportVO));reportBuilder.setDataSource(resultSet); 
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(reportFilePath);
   reportBuilder.toPdf(fileOutputStream);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the export menu I used "copy required libraries into a sum-folder....
instead of using "package required libraries...

now it works,
I'm not really sure why, but it works :)